# html css How create list with <a>links like table

Tags: html, css, list, html-table, hyperlink

List is `<a>` links with some elements inside `<a>`. All `<a>` links to internal website pages. How to make it look like a table? Is it possible?

| Thumbnail column | Term column | Description column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| thumbnail_1 | term_1 | description_1 |
| thumbnail_2 | term_2 | description_2 |

```html
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>thumbnail column</div>
      <div>term column</div>
      <div>description column</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="link_1">
        <img src="src_thumbnail_1" alt="thumbnail_1">
        <div>term_1</div>
        <div>description_1</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="link_2">
        <img src="src_thumbnail_2" alt="thumbnail_2">
        <div>term_2</div>
        <div>description_2</div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Why not just use a `table`?

Comment: @Paulie_D, Using `<table>` for a navigation list may violate semantics since `<table>` is typically used for tabular data, not for navigation. In such cases, `<div>` can be a better option because you can use semantic classes or markup to ensure list semantics. I create list code with `<div>` https://jsfiddle.net/h8tfjznx/1. If there is no other answer on how to do a task using lists, then I will post an answer with this code.

Comment: This is clearly tabular data... so a table is warranted.

Comment: @Paulie_D, Thank you. Than, with `<table>` case, it is need divided one <a> element into three identical <a> elements that will refer to each and the same thing. Is this correct?

Comment: Yep, but that should not be a problem

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
 <head>
            <style> 
                ul {
                    display: flex;
                    align-items: center;
                    justify-content: center;
                    flex-direction: column;
                }
                
                ul li a {
                    width: 200px;
                }
                
                ul li {
                    display: flex;
                    align-items: flex-start;
                    justify-content: space-between;
                }
                
                ul li.body {
                    align-items: center;
                }
                
                ul li.body img {
                    width: 100px;
                    height: 100px;
                }
                
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <ul> 
                <li class="header">
                    <a>thumbnail column</a>
                    <a>term column</a>
                    <a>description column</a>
                </li>
                <li class="body">
                    <a><img src="" alt="thumbnail_1"></a>
                    <a>term_1</a>
                    <a>description_1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="body">
                    <a><img src="" alt="thumbnail_2"></a>
                    <a>term_2</a>
                    <a>description_2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But your code divided one <a> element into three identical <a> elements that will refer to each and the same thing. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

To give your layout a table look one solution is too use the `table` `th` and `td` elements on your current html.

For more info check [table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)

This will give you the basic structure for your table. To give the table a visual look of a basic table, you could use CSS. For example, adding `border: 1px solid #ddd;` to your table cells will give it the look of lines inside a table.

---

The results will be something like this:

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
    th, td {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: left;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Thumbnail column</th>
      <th>Term column</th>
      <th>Description column</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="link_1">
          <img src="src_thumbnail_1" alt="thumbnail_1">
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>term_1</td>
      <td>description_1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="link_2">
          <img src="src_thumbnail_2" alt="thumbnail_2">
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>term_2</td>
      <td>description_2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

From this point on you can customize your table look farther.

Comment: I need to make a list with links. As far as I've read the documentation correctly, it's best to do this as a list using <ul > or <ol> elements. The <table> has a clear purpose for displaying certain information in tabular form, for example, inside a paragraph. In addition your code divided one <a> element into three identical <a> elements that will refer to each and the same thing. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes if you need to display a list you should probably do it with `ul` or `li`. And use a `table` to display things in a table format. For your case, I would prefer to use `table` because you want to give your links a table look. so it's not a list ( at least visually)

Comment: Using <table> for a navigation list may violate semantics since <table> is typically used for tabular data, not for navigation. In such cases, <div> can be a better option because you can use semantic classes or markup to ensure list semantics.

Comment: I create list code with <div> https://jsfiddle.net/h8tfjznx/1/.  If there is no other answer on how to do a task using lists, then I will post an answer with this code.

Comment: *"Using <table> for a navigation"* Correct me if I am wrong but what you have are links to external sources, not navigation

Comment: Forgive me, maybe I didn't use the term "navigation" correctly. All links go to internal website pages.

Comment: In that case, I would also use css to style the navigation look.

Comment: What exactly do you recommend using css to style the navigation for? For `<div>` (in my code  jsfiddle.net/h8tfjznx/1 ) or `<ul>`/`<ol>`?

Comment: I think that for this case divs are ok, just make sure to have meaningful class names so it will be clear for others who read your code.